# Dart, constraints on Generics?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints, dart

Is there a Dart equivalent syntax to the c# ability to specify type constraints on a generic type, e.g. in C#-like syntax `where TBase is SomeType`:

```
class StackPanel<TBase> extends Panel<TBase> where TBase : SomeType{

}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can specify type constraints like this :

```dart
class StackPanel<TBase extends SomeType> extends Panel<TBase> {
}
```

The [language specification](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html#h.dkzw3xyky3rs) says :

> A type parameter `T` may be suffixed with an `extends` clause that specifies the *upper bound* for `T`. If no extends clause is present, the *upper bound* is `Object`. It is a static type warning if a type parameter is a supertype of its *upper bound*. The bounds of type variables are a form of type annotation and have no effect on execution in production mode.