# Generic method in dart, how to return List<T> or bool in same method

Tags: dart

I'm writing this very generic method that checks if the json has the ok key, and if the ok key is true. Otherwire it returns exceptions.

```
  //Verifies if json has "ok" and "ok" is true.
  List<T> isOk(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json.containsKey("ok") && json["ok"]) {
        if (json.containsKey("response")) {
          List<T> l = json["response"].map((Map model) => T.fromJson(model)).toList();
          return l;
        } else if (json.containsKey("reason")) {
          //TODO: return reason number too
          throw new ApiException(1, json["reason"]);
        } else {
          throw new ApiException(1, "json parse error without reason");
        }
    } else {
      throw new ApiException(1, "json parsing error");
    }
  }
```

There are two problems with this code. First, the intellisense gives me this error:

```
The name 'T' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
```

I simply followed this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42004696/10116440 (yes, my method is inside a class)

What is wrong?

Secondly, I'd also like to return true or false for some cases not a list. I cannot just change `List<T>` by `T` in the return type, because I need to use the inner `T` of `List` in `T.fromJson(model)`. So how can I accomodate the two cases: return List when `json["response"]` is an array, and return `true` when `json["response"]` is a json document?

**Here's my document:**

```
class Billing {
  Billing(){}
  String name;
  String status;
  double value;
  String expiration;
  factory Billing.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$BillingFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$BillingToJson(this);
}
```

Comment: A couple things. First, if the method is in a class, does the class declare the generic type `T`? Second, you can't use `T` to call factory constructors or static methods on whatever type `T` is supposed to represent, so `T.fromJson` isn't going to fly.

Comment: Also, no, you can't return multiple types from a single method in Dart. The closest you can get is to make a container class that has all possible return values as fields and check them when the method returns. Otherwise, you can look at a package like sealed_unions or freezed to return a class union type. Ultimately, though, if you find yourself needing to return two values of wildly different types from a single method, chances are your approach could use a rethink anyway.

Comment: @Abion47 ok, now I see, I forgot to do `isOk<T>`. Do you have an idea on what I can do to solve the `T.fromJson` problem? Couldn't I simply change `factory Order.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$OrderFromJson(json);` to `fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$OrderFromJson(json);`?

Comment: To call an instance method you need an instance, which doesn't help if the goal is to _create_ an instance. It might be worth reconsidering if this is the right place to use generics at all or if a simple factory method would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Abion47 one workaround would be `T t` then calling `t.fromJson`, rigth? I don't see a way of not using generics. I have lots of models, and I want to be able to deserialize json into them. But first, I need to check if the json is ok. This is what my function does. I think generics is the only way I can do this without reusing the same code. I also don't understand the suggestion of using factory constructors. My `Order` class had a factory constructor `Order.fromJson` already.

Comment: Where is the JSON coming from? Are you trying to create one method that handles the results of a ton of different API calls? Because if that's the case, you should be mapping specific models to the call that creates them. Trying to create one method that can arbitrarily create dozens or hundreds of different models that have nothing to do with each other is a pretty egregious violation of the single responsibility principle.

Comment: You could create an empty model instance and then call `fromJson` on it to populate it, sure, but then you lose the ability to ensure required fields. The entire purpose of a constructor is to set up the object then, so if you allow empty constructors and defer the population of the object later, you run the risk of something going wrong and you ending up with an empty object. It's pretty code-smelly.

Comment: Also, I said "factory method". Not "factory constructor". As in the pattern, not the language feature. Have the method return an object based on inheritance rather than generics. (i.e. Return a `Model` where the exact type you return is a subclass of `Model` rather than some arbitrary type `T`.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a value based only on a type variable. You have to pass the `fromJson` method to the function. If you do that, then everything else is simple and almost exactly as you wrote it:

```dart
/// Verifies that [json] has "ok" and "ok" is true.
List<T> isOk<T>(Map<String, dynamic> json, 
                T fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> model)) {
  if (json.containsKey("ok") && json["ok"] == true) {
      if (json.containsKey("response")) {
        return [for (var model in json["response"] as List) 
                   fromJson(model as Map<String, dynamic>)];
      } else if (json.containsKey("reason")) {
        //TODO: return reason number too
        throw ApiException(1, json["reason"]);
      } else {
        throw ApiException(1, "json parse error without reason");
      }
  } else {
    throw ApiException(1, "json parsing error");
  }
}
```

Where you use it, you write:

```dart
List<Floo> floos = isOK(json, (model) => Floo.fromJson(model));
```

This should automatically infer the type parameter as `Floo`.
(This assumes that `Floo.fromJson` is a constructor. If it's a static function, then you can  just write `Floo.fromJson` instead of `(model) => Floo.fromJson(model)`).

Comment: The getter 'fromJson' isn't defined for the class 'Billing'.
Try importing the library that defines 'fromJson', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'fromJson'.

Comment: I'm getting this problem. I updated my question with the Billing class. Can you take a look on what's wrong? The fromJson method is there

Comment: As I mentioned below, you cannot tear off a constructor, so you have to wrap it. I'll update the answer to make that the example.