# Generic Programming: How can I access a class "fromMap" factory constructor from a Generic class

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

How to access a class "fromMap" factory constructor from a Generic class.

For example, Here is a very simplified class and method:

```
    abstract class DBbase<T> {
      dynamic convert(dynamic input) {
        T u = T.fromMap(input.toMap());
        return u;
      }
    }
    class DB<UserModel> extends DBbase {}
```

The **"T.fromMap" ** doesn't work a although the "UserModel" does have the method within.

If I change that line to:

```
    UserModel u2 = UserModel.fromMap(input.toMap());
```

then it works, but this defeats the purpose of defining the type as a generic.

Comment: You cannot.  Instead consider having the caller pass a callback to your function to construct an object of the desired type.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have done that in the past but with all the generic programming under-the-hood, I'd hope there was a way to do it generically based on the Model passed in as T

Comment: I think you can read this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42004475/how-to-create-a-generic-method-in-dart