# Calling Generic Types function

Tags: dart, generics

is it possible to call generic types function.

if not is there a different approach to something like this.

```
someFunction<T>(){
 T.anotherFunction();
}
```

EDIT

```
MyModel model = NetworkClient.sendRequest<MyModel>(url);
```

```
static Future<T> sendRequest<T>(String URL){
  //send request 
  var res = data.toString();
  return T.fromJson(json.decode(res))
}
```

Comment: Not possible in Dart. Can you provide are more detailed example with some context of the problem. For right now, no, there are no other way to do it but maybe if we know more about the problem, we can figure something out.

Comment: im writing out the network class for a project in flutter and was wondering if there was clean way of getting a typed model out @julemand101 I'll edit the question for more context

Answer (score 2):

```
void main() {
  someFunction(Foo());
  someFunction(Bar());
}

someFunction<T>(T t) {
  if (t is Foo)
    t.fooFunc();
  else if (t is Bar)
    t.barFunc();
  else
    throw Exception("Unknown type: ${t.runtimeType}");
}

class Foo {
  void fooFunc() {
    print("foo");
  }
}

class Bar {
  void barFunc() {
    print("bar");
  }
}
```

Comment: You should never use `runtimeType` for other purposes than debugging. Instead, use the `is` operator like `(t is Foo)`.

Comment: yes, the alternate code could be `if(t is Foo)...` instead of `switch`. Thanks, for mentioning that. I looked it up, it can be done https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/35052 but not recommended https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802419/how-do-i-check-type-of-an-object-in-a-switch-case/42802802#42802802

Comment: @Doc this can work but be wondering if I could do it in a way where I don't have to update the network decode every time I add a new model

Comment: What is "generic" about this? Instead of `T` you could have used `dynamic` or `Object` for the same effect. I don't think this is a good solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put your method (lets say `MyMethod`) in an interface or base class. Lets say `MyInterface`.

Then use a [constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698873/dart-constraints-on-generics) on your generic type:

```
someFunction<T extends MyInterface>(T t){
 t.MyMethod();
}
```

Since you cannot have constructors in an interface, your plan with the `fromJson` might not work out. I don't know your class structure. But you *can* write generics with specific constraints in mind.